# My 'hide selected object' script is not working

Tags: python

i have few object selected in my viewport. When i manually press 'H' key they are gone like they shoudl be. 
But whenever i copy and run this hide script

```
bpy.ops.object.hide_view_set(unselected=False)
```

Below error is shown

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.hide_view_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect 

```
````

Comment: Run this command: `for o in bpy.context.selected_objects: o.hide_set(True)`

Comment: WOW this works !! thank you

Comment: what should be the script to make them visible again???
@BlenderDadaist

Comment: You need to store the object list (`objs = bpy.context.selected_objects`) before calling hide and call set_hide(False) on this list (`for o in objs: o.set_hide(False)`) to make them visible.